# Upload multiple files/images using newman command in Jenkins

Tags: file-upload, postman, newman

Running a Postman API using Newman command which currently uploads a single file. My requirement is to upload multiple files using this same API.

My current code which uploads a single file looks like this:-

```
"method": "POST",
                    "header": [],
                    "body": {
                        "mode": "formdata",
                        "formdata": [
                            {
                                "key": "file",
                                "description": "Jpeg image or video (mov or mp4)",
                                "type": "file",
                                "src": "C:\\Test\\abc.jpeg"
                            }

                        ]
                    }
```

In this very same code, I want to upload  multiple files.
Need some direction on how can I achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post multi file in postman/newman by sending multi POST requests - one file per request.
 So you can send many files executing one postman collection of requests.

Edit:
Example of form with 2 file field:

```
"method": "POST",
                "header": [],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "formdata",
                    "formdata": [
                        {
                            "key": "myFile1",
                            "description": "Jpeg image or video (mov or mp4)",
                            "type": "file",
                            "src": "C:\\Test\\abc.jpeg"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "myFile2",
                            "description": "Jpeg image or video (mov or mp4)",
                            "type": "file",
                            "src": "C:\\Test\\def.jpeg"
                        }

                    ]
                }
```

Comment: - the API as per business logic at my end requires 2 images to be uploaded.so sending multi post would not help here.

Comment: If your api accept multi file field inside one request you can use code lile upper

Comment: Tried above solution but then it gives an error as - `| 'Form param file, file load error: "C:\\Test\\def.jpeg", no such file'`. Also tried concatenating another file by making src as an array `"src": ["C:\\Test\\abc.jpeg","C:\\Test\\def.jpeg"]` but then it gives an error ` | 'Form param `file`, file load error: invalid or missin
  | g file source'`

Comment: 1) Key must be diffrend - example update

2) If this not help: My example is the only one correct syntax for formdata. Did you tried send request basicly from Postman for test (without Newman)? Does it work in Postman with one and two files?

Comment: Tried with different keys but still the same issue. I executed the same API in Postman UI by sending/choosing 2 files at the same instant and that went well.

Comment: Your first solution worked for me (use multi post request to upload multiple images). I concluded this post discussion with my developer. Secondly, I also corrected the script to use jpeg(extension with which file was saved in the folder) earlier in my script I was using jpg.